# Puppet: How to execute a Exec resource if another Exec resource failed

Tags: exec, puppet

Is it possible to exec resource only when another exec resource is failed.

```
exec {'register_host':
   unless    => '/etc/is_host_exist.sh',
   command   => '/etc/script/register_host.sh -h hostname',
   path      => '/usr/bin:/usr/sbin/',
   provider  => 'shell',
   notify    => 'register_service',
}

exec {'register_service':
   command  => '/etc/script/register_service.sh -s svcname',
   path     => '/usr/bin:/usr/sbin/',
   provider => 'shell',
}
```

So, here I want to execute register_service when register_host is failed. Some how my dependenc logic is not working.

Thanks James

Comment: In this case you can simply do command1 || command2 ie ```/etc/script/register_host.sh -h hostname || /etc/script/register_service.sh -s svcname```

Answer (score 1):

*`Exec` resources are not idempotent and should be avoided if possible.*

Having said that, let's see what you want to happen, in pseudo-code:

```
register_host_success = register_host()
if (!register_host_success) {
  register_service()
}
```

`notify` is used

So, considering that `is_host_exist.sh` can check if `register_host` failed, then:

1. you need to `subscribe => Exec['register_host']`, so you ensure that whenever the `Exec['register_host']` is triggered your `Exec['register_service']` is also triggered,
2. you need to ensure that your `Exec['register_service']` is called only as a consequence of `Exec['register_host']`
3. you need to run `Exec['register_service']` only if the `Exec['register_host']` failed.

```rb
exec {'register_host':
   unless    => '/etc/is_host_exist.sh',
   command   => '/etc/script/register_host.sh -h hostname',
   path      => '/usr/bin:/usr/sbin/',
   provider  => 'shell',
}

exec {'register_service':
   command   => '/etc/script/register_service.sh -s svcname',
   path      => '/usr/bin:/usr/sbin/',
   provider  => 'shell',
   unless    => '/etc/is_host_exist.sh',
   refresh   => true,
   subscribe => Exec['register_host']
}
```

The presumption is that your scripts (`*.sh`) will `exit 0` on success and `exit` with `non 0` on failure. The `notify`/`subscribe` can be used inter-exchangeably, use whatever you consider best ( [more docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.17/lang_relationships.html) )